How good is performance of "has" operator in Kusto when RHS is not exactly one term?
The documentation on has operator talks about how we can benefit from term search. It also mentions that if the term is shorter than three characters, the search falls back into column scan rather than using term index.
Reviewing some of our monitoring queries, I found examples of using of has similar to these:
Message has "Heart Beat"
Message has "ends:"

Re-reading the documentation, I could not find mentioning of how the search goes if the RHS is more than one term or a term plus some non-alphanumerical characters. Tests show that functionally it works as expected, correctly identifying occurrence of a string as if it was a single whole term, but performance-wise, do we still benefit from term index or the search falls back to scanning column value?

"Heart Beat" is indexed has two words, "Heart" & "Beat" (because space is a separator).
has searches the index for each word separately (actually has is case insensitive, so it looks for any case variation of these words. Consider using has_cs for case sensitive search), intersects the results and then search the data itself (within the potential rows) for the exact match of "Heart Beat".
"ends:" is indexed has "ends" (because colon in a separator).
has searches the index for "end" and then search the data itself (within the potential rows) for the exact match of "ends:".

Thank you. Do you think the documentation on has* operators can be improved? Currently it assumes that the RHS is always a single term, but apparently we can use them more flexibly. In particular, the information you posted is important for understanding both performance and semantics of has* operators.

The short answer - "Yes" :-)

As per the documentation,
A term is a maximal sequence of alphanumerical characters in a string. has operator will work based on the terms. AFAIK, In the case of RHS being more than one term, the term index will be better as it can ignore the special characters which will be treated as delimited characters. But in the second case ends:, the search falls back to column scan like contains for the special characters.
In the case of terms not more than 3 characters, it's better to use contains than has. You can see the same in the below examples.
Using has:

Using contains:


Thanks, but that does not answer my question. I was wondering about efficiency of the query in these cases. I realized that the wording of the question might have been unclear, which I fixed.

Performance wise, I think when the special characters involved, column scan like contains will be better as has might negate the advantages of the term index.

At this point, even a single-character term might be indexed. Typically, this would not be an English character due to its high frequency, but Korean, Japanese, and Chinese characters (or even some emojis) are likely to be indexed. I'll review the documentation within a couple of weeks.
